# How to set my Range to be variable range_Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to optimize the speed of my VBA code.

As Range3 is not always 150000 rows, sometimes there are less and sometimes more.

I would like to set my Range3 to be variable based on the actual number of rows.

My current VBA Code

```vb
Sub PROP()

Dim Sheet3 As String, Range3 as String


Sheet3 = "Raw Data"

Range3 = "B2:B150000"

Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Sheets(Sheet3).Range(Range3)

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get the last row# with `End(xlUp).Row`

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Sub PROP()
    Dim Sheet3 As String, sCol As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Sheet3 = "Raw Data"
    sCol = "B"
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    With Sheets(Sheet3)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow > 1 Then
            Set Rng1 = .Range("B2", sCol & lastRow)
            Debug.Print Rng1.Address
            ' your code
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: While I also use the `End`-technique frequently, it has it's pitfalls, for example when data is filtered or when you don't know the column that holds "the most" data. For a detailed discussion, see `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba`.